# Заставить работать функцию-транспорт логера Pino совместно с библиотекой Inquirer.js в CLI приложении на node.js

Tags: node.js, консоль, логирование

Inquirer.js обрабатывает пользовательский ввод в консоль. При использовании функции-транспорта логера Pino совместно с Inquirer.js не получается перенаправлять поток вывода данныйx stdout.

В приложении есть файл index.js:

```
'use strict';

const inquirer = require('inquirer');
const { getLogger } = require(`./logger`);

const logger = getLogger();

const test = function (answer) {
    logger.info(JSON.parse(answer));
};

const questions = [
    {
        type: 'input',
        name: 'question',
        message: 'question to user',
        default: function () {
            return '';
        },
    },
];

inquirer.prompt(questions).then((answer) => {
    test(JSON.stringify(answer, null, '  '));
});
```

файл logger.js:

```
'use strict';

let n = 0;
const logger = require(`pino`)({
    name: `test-pino`,
    level: process.env.LOG_LEVEL || `info`,
    mixin() {
        return { line: ++n };
    },
});

module.exports = {
    logger,
    getLogger(options = {}) {
        return logger.child(options);
    },
};
```

и файл transport.js

```
'use strict';

const split = require('split2');
const pump = require('pump');
const through = require('through2');

const myTransport = through.obj(function (chunk, enc, cb) {
    // do the necessary
    console.log(chunk);
    cb();
});

pump(process.stdin, split(JSON.parse), myTransport);
```

в консоле использую команду `LOG_LEVEL=debug node index.js | node transport.js` или `node index.js | node transport.js`.
В результате, функция транспорт в transport.js не работает. Но если не использовать Inquirer.js, то все прекрасно работает:

index.js:

```
'use strict';

const { getLogger } = require(`./logger`);

const logger = getLogger();

const test = function () {
    logger.info('it works');
};

test();
```

вывод в консоль:

```
{
  level: 30,
  time: 1602263541760,
  pid: 14248,
  hostname: 'DESKTOP-9IG2DCD',
  name: 'test-pino',
  line: 1,
  msg: 'it works'
}
```

Как заставить pino и Inquirer.js работать вместе?